# Spotify Client Credentials Auth using Fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

How can I get the spotify api token using `fetch`?

The spotify website has an example like this:

```
var client_id = 'CLIENT_ID';
var client_secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET';

var authOptions = {
  url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
  },
  form: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
  },
  json: true
};

request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    var token = body.access_token;
  }
});
```

Can that be translated into `fetch`? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test it with real credentials, but it should work:

```js
var client_id = 'CLIENT_ID';
var client_secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET';

fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + client_id + '&client_secret=' + client_secret,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
})
.then(r => r.json())
.then(r => {
    console.log(r.access_token)
})
```

You could use `new FormData()` to make form data too instead of urlencoded.

Answer (score 0):

"mmm107"'s solution works.

Here's another approach that looks a bit more familiar, using fetch with a similar set of request options to the [client credentials documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/).

Main differences are in adding the `'Content-Type'` option within the headers, and replacing the `form` object property with a `body` string property.

```
const client_id = require('./keys.js').client_id; // Your client id
const client_secret = require('./keys.js').client_secret; // Your secret

// get authorisation token from Spotify
async function getSpotifyToken() {
    const url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
    response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (Buffer.from(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')),
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: 'grant_type=client_credentials',
        json: true
    });
    if (response.ok) {
        const jsonResponse = await response.json();
        console.log(jsonResponse);
    } else {
        console.log(response.statusText);
        throw new Error(`Request failed! Status code: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
    }
}

getSpotifyToken()
```